# How should I repair this capped duct which leaks during heavy rains?

Tags: roof

There used to be an evaporative cooler here, but it was removed. Removing all of it and patching the hole with new wood is certainly ideal, but I was hoping to get by until professional work is otherwise needed.

The water appeared to be coming down the outside of the duct when I looked at it from the underside, but I'm really not sure what is leaking, the duct or the penetration.  How should I go about sealing this thing up?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like it's leaking due to corrosion of the duct itself. There are two avenues here, as I see it.

**The cheap 'n lazy way:**

Slather some goo over everything. Coat it with roofing sealant--whatever's readily available. Make sure you get it under the edges of the shingles where the corners of the metal assembly reside.

**The right way:**

Remove the duct and repair the roof.

1. On a cool day or early in the morning (before the sun), carefully remove enough shingles to fully expose the duct flashing. Use a putty knife or flatbar to separate the layers, then pull the nails. Cut back to full tabs in preparation for new shingle fitment.
2. Pull the nails in the flashing, remove the cap, and disconnect the duct at a convenient point below the roof deck.
3. Fill the hole in the decking. The simplest way is probably to float some wood backing by screwing into it through the decking, spanning the hole. Then lay in a patch of plywood or OSB of the appropriate thickness.
4. Repair the underlayment. If this is high up the slope, fit asphalt felt (tar paper) with correct lapping. If it's down near the wall line, use self-adhesive weather barrier product per local rules and best practice.
5. Install new shingles. Working from the bottom up, fit and nail down each course.

Answer (score 4):

Without further disassembly and better pictures, it will be difficult to tell exactly what is wrong and what it will take to fix. In my mind, the two most likely causes of the leak are poor or failed flashing and sealing, or the duct itself has failed and is leaking. Either one of those problems will be easy for a roofer to fix, and probably not too expensive.

The best fix would be to remove it altogether and patch and shingle the hole in the roof. That will probably not be much more expensive than fixing the other problems I suggested.